# run $formatters each time model value changes

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angular-ui-router, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am using the `$formatters` property to do masking of text box, where user can enter account number.The text box while typing should show `*` instead of actual account number.

But using `$formatters` is not working as expected , as its running only once when user runs the application. Once we change the model value, the `$formatters` function is not getting invoked. Do we have any work around to run the `$formatters` function each time when the model value changes.

Comment: Why aren't you using `input type="password"`?

Comment: I have to show the masking with # character.

Answer (score 1):

Can you post your code here ?
On the top of my head i can suggest something like this

```
.directive('changeValue', function () {
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function (scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {

      ngModel.$formatters.push(function(){

        var value = ngModel.$modelValue;
              var string ="";
              for(var i=0;i<(value.length);i++){
                string +="#";

              }
              return string
      })
        element.bind('keydown', function () {
            console.log(ngModel);
            scope.$apply(setAnotherValue);
        });
        function setAnotherValue() {
            var data = angular.copy(ngModel);
             var value = element.val();
              var string ="";
              for(var i=0;i<(value.length);i++){
                string +="#";

              }

              //element.val(string).trigger('input')

              // ngModel.$formatters.push(function(){
              //   return string
              // })

              ngModel.$viewValue = string;
              ngModel.$render();

              ngModel.$parsers.push(function(){
                return ngModel.$modelValue;
              })

        }
    }
};
```

});

[link to plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/0Z2bYnVQU0sJ3WD1hKif?p=preview)
This isnt the perfect code, will be home in couple of hours, in mean time can you check if this works ?

Comment: Thanks Anand.The solution works fine for the masking functionality.But how can we get the actual value of account number in the text box.The plunker you attached was not opening, seems like the site is down.I tried creating a new fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/dxrk2mr2/. But here when the name property is printed it just gives the first character.

Comment: After again reading your question I was able to understand what you are looking for but there is no direct way of doing this by angular js only , as user writes data to your input field parsers trigger in and add the value that is changed to "#" by your snippet to your model value, for model value to be same as what user entered  when user edits the field, you will need  to make use of CSS  (-webkit-text-security property)as well or any masking js library.
2) Also for CSS property to work, you will need to keep the input type="text" as type="password" cannot be overridden (security reasons)